# How to customize Popup closing behavior?

Tags: qt, qml, popup

I created a control, and when I click it, the popup will be displayed on the left and right sides. Like:

[image]

[image]

There may be many other buttons on the main interface. I hope that when I click the button, the popup will not close, but when I click other external areas, the popup will close.

I thought of using closePolicy, but when I set Popup.NoAutoClose, no matter I click the outer area or the button control, the popup will not be closed. When I set Popup.CloseOnPressOutside, the popup will be closed.

So how to customize the closing behavior of the popup? Or is there any other custom control way to achieve such a requirement(may not be popup)?

[image]

**Edit**

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15


Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MenuSpinner{
        id: menuId
        x: 100
        y: 50
    }
    Column{
        x: 500
        spacing: 10

        Repeater{
            model: 3
            Button{
                width: 100
                height: 50
                text: index
                onPressed: {
                    console.log("pressed" + index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MenuSpinner.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Rectangle{
    width: 300
    height: 50
    property bool bTextClicked: false


    onBTextClickedChanged: {
        if(bTextClicked) popup.open()
        else popup.close()
    }





    Rectangle{
        width: 100
        height: parent.height
        x: rect1.width
        border.color: "blue"
        Text {
            id: text
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            text: qsTr("value")
            font.pixelSize: 16

        }
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                bTextClicked = !bTextClicked
            }
        }
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        leftPadding: 0
        rightPadding: 0
        topPadding: 0
        bottomPadding: 0
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        background: Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "transparent"
            //border.color: "black"
        }
        Rectangle{
            id: rect1
            width: 100
            height: 50
            Text {
                text: qsTr("pop1")
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                font.pixelSize: 16
            }
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "blue"
        }

        Rectangle{
            id: rect2
            x: parent.width - rect1.width
            width: 100
            height: 50
            Text {
                text: qsTr("pop2")
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                font.pixelSize: 16
            }
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "blue"
        }
        onClosed: {
            bTextClicked = false
            console.log("close")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @JarMan I have updated my question and you can refer to it.

Comment: You want the popups to close when the user clicks outside of the button or the popups themselves? If that's the case, the code already does what you want from what I can see.

Comment: @Mitch But I hope that the popup will not close when I click the external button.

Comment: Do they have to be popups? It would also be possible to create items anchored to the left/right of your button, maybe add some shadow. That way you can code the logic for closing of the "popups" yourself (for example one property in the upper QML code stating which button is currently selected/expanded)

Comment: Then you should update the question to be more specific.

Comment: @Amfasis They don't have to be popups, but I can't control the control to close automatically when clicked outside (like Pop.CloseOnPressOutside), because the control may be used on multiple pages, so I need to control its closing logic.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to catch mouse clicks on the window itself. Add a function or signal to MenuSpinner that can be called to close the popup. Any clicks to the other buttons should still work.

main.qml

```
Window {

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            menuId.closePopup();
        }
    }

    MenuSpinner{
        id: menuId
    }
}
```

MenuSpinner.qml

```
Rectangle{
    function closePopup() {
        popup.close();
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but it is more complicated in actual application, because I have a lot of MenuSpinners, and they may be on multiple interfaces, this operation will increase a lot of work, so I hope to have direct control of the components and buttons Interaction between.

Comment: And if I have two MenuSpinners, the first one will not close when I press the second one, but I need to close it. I just hope it won't close when I click on some other control like button.